# XenCenter can't connect to server; missing methodResponse element

Tags: xen, xenserver, xmlrpc

I'm trying to connect to the server (which I can ping successfully) in XenCenter but I keep getting an error that states "Response XML not valid XML-RPC - missing methodResponse element" . I tried looking up the error, but all I figured out is that I should check the file that the parts `<methodResponse> .... </methodResponse>` is at/ should be at. I'm really not sure where to look for that file though. I'm using Xencenter in Windows 7 if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. It was a silly error of non-matching IP addresses. I had set up XenServer to use DHCP for IP addresses and it configured it using the BMC IP address, not the ethernet port IP address. I basically fixed this error by going on XenServer and selecting "Network and Management Interface" and then changing IP address statically to the right number.

Comment: Thanks for answering with the solution to this problem, it might help somebody in a similar situation.